# How do bad grades affect my chances of getting a Master's degree in biomedical engineering?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I want to get into a master's program in biomedical engineering. The university I attend does not offer a biomedical engineering undergraduate degree, so I decided to major in chemical engineering since it seemed like a really good option at the time. However, I've been making low grades the moment I started my chemical engineering classes. I have 5 C's now and I've already had to withdraw and retake a class. I'm told that such grades are common in this program at my university (which was something I should have realized at the time). I was able to take Pass for all these classes due to the pandemic. I'm now well into my junior year for this degree and my grades get worse and worse every single semester no matter how hard I try to get them back up. As much as I hate to admit it, I've lost passion in my work due to all the stress and am just trying to survive my classes. I feel pressured to stay with this major because its the only major on campus that has research opportunities close to biomedical engineering and switching my major would mean taking summer classes which would prevent me from doing research. I already have some research experience but no publication which I was hoping to get this semester before I ruined it with my grades. Should I just stick this out and do research over the summer and just move on to my masters? Should I change majors to salvage my GPA (because I feel like my classes are going to get much worse)? How do I fix the mess I've gotten myself into? Before my academic performance dropped, I was hoping to apply for biomedical engineering at Vanderbilt University. Is that even possible at this point?